# Access object in React state not submiting fields value to state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with accessing my object that i have in my state.
My Register form currently looks like this:

```
class Register extends Component {
  state = {
     formData: {
       name: '',
       email: '',
       password: '',
       password2: '',
     },


  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    const { formData } = this.state
    this.setState({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = this.state;
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (password !== password2) {
        console.log('password do not match');
      } else {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    };
    return (
      <section className='container'>
        <h1 className='large text-primary'>Sign Up</h1>
        <p className='lead'>
          <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Create Your Account
        </p>
        <form
          className='form'
          action='create-profile.html'
          onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Name'
              name='name'
              value={name}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='email'
              placeholder='Email Address'
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <small className='form-text'>
              This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image, use a
              Gravatar email
            </small>
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='password'
              placeholder='Password'
              name='password'
              minLength='6'
              value={password}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='password'
              placeholder='Confirm Password'
              name='password2'
              value={password2}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              minLength='6'
            />
          </div>
          <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' value='Register' />
        </form>
        <p className='my-1'>
          Already have an account? <a href='login.html'>Sign In</a>
        </p>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Right now I did change my state to:

```
state = {
    // formData: {
    //   name: '',
    //   email: '',
    //   password: '',
    //   password2: '',
    // },

    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: '',
  };
```

and just get this working just as it is with no formData Object. But how can I access this formData?
With some various attempts a was able to:

put data only in one form field. After typing Name value and after that typing email value, my name was erased from form.
- I was unable to type in any form fields.
- I was able to change state but not in my formData object. I had empty object and my fields values in state.
- tried `const {...formData} = this.state`, also did not worked

Not sure what is the issue.

Thanks for any clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes

```
class Register extends Component {
  state = {
     formData: {
       name: '',
       email: '',
       password: '',
       password2: '',
     },


  };

  onChange = (e) => {

    // setting formData in the state properly
    const { formData } = this.state;
    let newFormData = {...formData};
    newFormData[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ 
      formData:newFormData
    });
  };

  // onSubmit Handler outside render
  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {

      // Destructing required fields from state.formData and using it
      const {password,password2} = this.state.formData;
      e.preventDefault();
      if (password !== password2) {
        console.log('password do not match');
      } else {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    };

  render() {
    // Destructing required fields from state.formData and using it
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = this.state.formData;

    return (
      <section className='container'>
        <h1 className='large text-primary'>Sign Up</h1>
        <p className='lead'>
          <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Create Your Account
        </p>
        <form
          className='form'
          action='create-profile.html'
          onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Name'
              name='name'
              value={name}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='email'
              placeholder='Email Address'
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <small className='form-text'>
              This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image, use a
              Gravatar email
            </small>
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='password'
              placeholder='Password'
              name='password'
              minLength='6'
              value={password}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <input
              type='password'
              placeholder='Confirm Password'
              name='password2'
              value={password2}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              minLength='6'
            />
          </div>
          <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' value='Register' />
        </form>
        <p className='my-1'>
          Already have an account? <a href='login.html'>Sign In</a>
        </p>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Wroking like a charm. I was doing something similar, but not sure why it was not working. Thanks